# Open Directory directory domain name on Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos, dns, openldap

I can retrieve the logged in user name using NSUserName(), but how do I get the Open Directory "directory domain name" or other domain he is a member of? i.e. similar to the notion in Windows where a logged-in user is DOMAIN\USERNAME, where DOMAIN is his local machine, workgroup or Active Directory domain.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while to say the least, But perhaps have you managed to find a descent cocoa/openDirectory method for retrieving the current active domain ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with [Directory Services](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/Open_Directory_Ref/). Alternatively, check out the new Open Directory APIs introduced in 10.6; you have a choice between [a Core-Foundation-based API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/OpenDirectoryFramework/) and [a Cocoa-based API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/Open_Directory/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I don't see a recipe for locating the directory domain name. Can you point me to some code which does this or even anything similar to this?

Comment: did you get the solution?