# Obtain peferred domain controller (Active Directory) in Mac OS X programmatically

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, dns, network-programming

I'd like to get preferred domain controller name/adress on Mac, joined to Active Directory (MS Windows Server with Domain Controller) programmatically with C/Objective-C. The better solution for now is parsing output of `dsconfigad -show` commandline utility where are such lines:

```
Advanced Options - Administrative
  Preferred Domain controller    = 192.168.XXX.XXX
```

I already tried Open Directory API, as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756143/open-directory-directory-domain-name-on-mac-os-x), but it fails to access nodes far than full name of domain:

```
// domainNode: "/Active Directory/MYDOMAIN/mydomain.local"
NSArray *domainSubNodes = [domainNode subnodeNamesAndReturnError:&err];
[domainSubNodes count]; // count is 0
```

Do I need to perform some kind of authorization to access subnodes of domain and how to perform it?
Is there any posix/BSD functions that can obtain domain controller name from pure C code?