# Mac os x get domain name programmatically

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, networking

I know about windows workgroup and iwant to get workgroup of my Mac. As i see [Open Directory directory domain name on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756143/open-directory-directory-domain-name-on-mac-os-x) but could not get rid of my problem.
I wish to find the workgroup (as in Windows) of my Mac.
Please give me some code example to go ahead towards solution.
I want domain name as desribed in
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/what-is-the-difference-between-a-domain-a-workgroup-and-a-homegroup

Comment: the SMB configuration is stored in the dictionary "State:/Network/Global/SMB" - you can access it via the CLI using `scutil` and `show State:/Network/Global/SMB`, the data is part of the SystemConfiguration framework.

Comment: @hPetesh Thanks It really work as expected. This is enough for me but  i will appreciate your help further if you give me programmatic solution in obj C.(If possible) :)

Comment: It is really good that users reply early to questions and share knowledge. For above problem if anyone have programmatic solution, please post for convenience.It will be helpful.

Comment: I've updated with an answer that reads the data. It's a Core Foundation based API, so it's more C than objective C looking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The System Configuration framework is a C api, so it's a little bit messy, but this *should* work ok without leaking:

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkConfiguration.h>

SCDynamicStoreRef storeRef = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"GetWorkgroup", NULL, NULL);
CFPropertyListRef global = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue (storeRef,CFSTR("State:/Network/Global/SMB"));
id workgroup = [(__bridge NSDictionary *)global valueForKey:@"Workgroup"];
NSLog(@"Workgroup: %@", workgroup);
CFRelease(global);
CFRelease(storeRef);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder why you not added objective c in your profile. When i post for you to answer, i saw your profile.Thats why i reposted for all. But i think you should add objective c to your profile. At last its your choice. Thanks a lot for your answer.