# How to get Domain name programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new in Mac OS app development. Within app I am trying to get domain name. I tried with below code

```
NSLog(@"hostName is %@",[[NSHost currentHost]names]);
```

and it shows me the list of hosts as below

```
hostName is (
    "zenmactest.local",
    "ZenMacTest.local",
    localhost
)
```

But it does not show my host name which must be like `ind.mycompany.com`.

How to get hostname in Mac OS app?

Comment: possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933230/mac-os-x-get-domain-name-programmaticaly

Answer (score 1):

@Cole's pointer is a good one, the SystemConfiguration framework has a convenience API for getting the current hostname.

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
...
SCDynamicStoreRef store = SCDynamicStoreCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("getting the host name"), NULL, NULL);
NSString *hostName = (NSString *)SCDynamicStoreCopyLocalHostName(store);
NSLog(@"hostname = %@", hostName);
CFRelease(store);
```